# Add panel border to ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have been asked to place a full border around my plot below:

[image]

Using `panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black")` results in losing in the plot becoming blank.

I can't use `theme_bw()` as it does not have the same functionality as the usual theme, the code I am currently using is below:

```
graph<-ggplot(d,aes(x=d$AOE, y=d$MEI)
            )+
  geom_point(shape=20, size=3)+
  geom_rug()+
  annotate("text", x = -1.1, y = 14000, label = "27/04/2011") +
  annotate("text", x = -1.3, y = 10400, label = "03/04/1974") +
  xlab("MEI")+
  ylab("AOE")+
  scale_y_log10()+
  theme(axis.text.y   = element_text(size=14),
        axis.text.x   = element_text(size=14),
        axis.title.y  = element_text(size=14),
        axis.title.x  = element_text(size=14),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")
  )

graph
```

Any advice on how to get a full black border would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 120, accepted):

To use `panel.border` you also have to specify a blank fill using `fill=NA`.

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point() + geom_rug() +
  theme(axis.text.y   = element_text(size=14),
        axis.text.x   = element_text(size=14),
        axis.title.y  = element_text(size=14),
        axis.title.x  = element_text(size=14),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=5)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Additionally, if the panel.border is thin it can be good to remove the axis.line ("axis.line = element_blank()") to avoid an uneven box.

Comment: I get: Warning message:
The `size` argument of `element_rect()` is deprecated as of ggplot2 3.4.0.
ℹ Please use the `linewidth` argument instead.

Answer (score 27):

You can use `theme_bw()` and `theme()` together. This should work:

```
# creating some data
set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(MEI=rnorm(100), AOE=rlnorm(100, 10, 5))

# creating the plot
ggplot(d,aes(x=MEI, y=AOE)) +
  geom_point(shape=20, size=3) +
  geom_rug() +
  scale_y_log10() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(colour = "black", size=4))
```

this gives:
[image]

---

A solution without `theme_bw()` and inspired by @Andrie, but with the use of `panel.background` instead of `panel.border`:

```
ggplot(d,aes(x=MEI, y=AOE)) +
  geom_point(shape=20, size=3) +
  geom_rug() +
  scale_y_log10() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(colour = "black", size=4, fill=NA))
```

this will give the exact same plot. The difference between `panel.background` and `panel.border` is that `panel.background` is drawn underneath the plot and `panel.border` is drawn on top of the plot.

Comment: None of those methods, nor even them combined, work with size=1, which is the normally used for publications.

Comment: I'm not sure what your code looks like, but using `panel.background` with `element_rect()` worked for me using `size = 1`.

Answer (score 11):

If you use any of the `panel.` options you will get a border around each individual facet when facetting. If you want a border around the outside of the entire plot, title etc included, then use `plot.background`. E.g:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point() + geom_rug() +
  labs(title = "Hello plot!") +
  facet_wrap(~cyl) +
  theme(axis.text.y   = element_text(size=14),
        axis.text.x   = element_text(size=14),
        axis.title.y  = element_text(size=14),
        axis.title.x  = element_text(size=14),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        plot.background = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=5)
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>