# Adjust the height of plot in ggplot2 and plotly

Tags: r, shiny, hover, plotly

I have created a simple line chart in plotly using ggplot2 and placed the plot in a box using box() function. However the plot overshoots the screen and I wish to resize the plot. Please help me with the same.

```
library(plotly)

datn <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
supp dose length
OJ  0.5  13.23
OJ  1.0  22.70
OJ  2.0  26.06
VC  0.5   7.98
VC  1.0  16.77
VC  2.0  26.14
')

p <- ggplot(data=datn, aes(x=dose, y=length, group=supp, colour=supp)) +
geom_line() +
geom_point()

p <- ggplotly(p)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** sorry, I missed your comment that you were using `box()` to add a plot border (it wasn't in your example code). I'd recommend instead using [ggplot2's panel border functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191833/add-panel-border-to-ggplot2):

```
p = p +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size = 3))
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL:** The code you've supplied isn't overshooting on my laptop:

[image]But if you need to, you can supply `ggplotly()` with explicit height and width arguments:

```
ggplotly(p, width = 500, height = 200)
```

[image]

The function has [some other nice arguments](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plotly/versions/4.7.1/topics/ggplotly) for controlling the appearance of your plot.

Comment: Thank you so much Rensa, this width and height attribute in ggplotly was what I was looking for. Great help pal, Thanks again.

Comment: No worries, @ASHMIN ☺️

Comment: If you could consider accepting the answer (the tick to the left of it), that'd be great :)