# Add Borders Around Entire ggplot2 Plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to draw a border around an entire ggplot2 plot, such as the box("figure") function would do in case of a Base R plot.

Have a look at the following example:

```
data <- data.frame(x = 1:5,
                   y = 1:5)

library("ggplot2")

ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

I would like to add a border around this plot as shown below:

[image]

I cannot believe that this information doesn't exist anywhere. Unfortunately, all I find is [how to add a panel border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191833/add-panel-border-to-ggplot2).

How could I add a border around the **ENTIRE** ggplot2 plot?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The theme element `plot.background` is an `element_rect`, which normally has a color of `NA`. Just change this to whatever color you like and adjust the `linewidth` to control the line width.

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(color = "deepskyblue3", linewidth = 3))
```

[image]